# Query seems to be really slow if there is no result set to return

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am using linq to sql in a web project. I got the sql below from the linq query and it works well in any case other than the not exists subquery returns empty

```sql
SELECT [t1].[Name] AS [CategoryName], [t1].[CategoryID] AS [categoryId]
FROM [Store].[CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappings] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [Store].[Categories] AS [t1] ON [t0].[CategoryID] = [t1].[CategoryID]
WHERE ([t1].[StorefrontID] = 73) AND (NOT (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [dbo].[DownloadLog] AS [t2]
    WHERE ([t2].[CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID] = [t0].[CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID]) AND (DATEPART(Hour, [t2].[DTS]) = 11) AND (CONVERT(DATE, [t2].[DTS]) = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))
    )))
GROUP BY [t1].[Name], [t1].[CategoryID]
```

The linq looks like this:

```
var notDLToUnion = (from ntdl in notDownloadedIds
                    join cat in cDataContext.Categories
                    on ntdl.CategoryID equals cat.CategoryID
                    where cat.StorefrontID == StorefrontID
                    group ntdl by new { cat.Name, cat.CategoryID } into t1
                    select new CategoryStruct { CategoryName = t1.Key.Name, Status = 0, AverageResponseTime = 0, categoryId = t1.Key.CategoryID });
```

What can i do to readjust my linq(or sql) to run just as fast if notDownloadedIds is an empty set?

Another avenue to this, i dont really need to group by cat.name and cat.categoryId... i only need to group by cat.Name, but i need access to cat.id, and there is a one to one relationship between the two.

Added Comments: some expermination has found some wierd results. Removing group by makes it speedy, removing one group by key makes it speedy, removing the subquery under Not exists(with or without empty set) makes it speedy. When the subquery has rows, its speedy.

It is of course not speedy as is, and it is also not speedy, if I inner join the categoryName to CategoryID after the group by.

Edit: adding downloadIds

```
 notDownloadedIds = cDataContext.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappings.Where(mapping =>!
currentLogs.Select(dll => dll.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID)
.Any(id => id ==mapping.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID));
```

Comment: This sounds more like a Sql performance problem than an actual LINQ problem. I suggest you try analyzing the query with Management Studio's performance tools before anything else. Once it runs smoothly as plain SQL then it should go just as well with LINQ.

Comment: I agree, im starting from the sql side, and moving back. but i figured id give out as much info as possible.

Comment: How do you get `notDownloadedIds`? There are some elements in the inferred `SQL` code that does not match your `LINQ` query, for example, all the conditions concerning `dates`.

Comment: @polkduran added notDownloadedIds

Comment: You're stacking three queries on top of each other (`currentLogs`, `notDownloadedIds`, and `notDLToUnion`). It's very likely that storing intermediate results from one of these is quicker.

Comment: Its not, each has a max of 53k rows. Im sure i could use a hashset, or dictionary to speed up a local searching process, but i perfer leaving it to sql.

Answer (score 1):

I'd remove the subquery and make it a LEFT OUTER JOIN like this

```
SELECT [t1].[Name] AS [CategoryName], [t1].[CategoryID] AS [categoryId]
FROM [Store].[CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappings] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [Store].[Categories] AS [t1] ON [t0].[CategoryID] = [t1].[CategoryID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[DownloadLog] AS [t2] 
    ON [t2].[CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID] = [t0].[CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID]) 
WHERE ([t1].[StorefrontID] = 73) 
    AND [t2].[CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID] IS NULL
    AND (DATEPART(Hour, [t2].[DTS]) = 11) 
    AND (CONVERT(DATE, [t2].[DTS]) = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
GROUP BY [t1].[Name], [t1].[CategoryID]
```

This was built off the top of my head and is untested but I believe it should net you the same result set, and might be faster.

Comment: This query always returns an empty set, ill look into editing it a little

Answer (score 0):

Im still not sure what was going on with the sql, but I ended up using linq in better fashion. When you make a linq statement

```
 (from f in foo
 join b in bar
 on b.id equals f.id
 select f)
```

It does not select the join between f and b, like I believed. it only selects f, one has to `select new {f,b}` in order to get both.

My fix for my linq ended up looking like this:

```
 var notDLToUnion =  (from final in
                                (from ntdl in notDownloadedIds
                                join cat in cDataContext.Categories
                                on ntdl.CategoryID equals cat.CategoryID
                                where cat.StorefrontID == StorefrontID
                                select new {ntdl,cat})
                            group final by new {final.cat.CategoryID} into t1
                            orderby t1.Key.CategoryID
                            select new CategoryStruct { CategoryName = t1.Max(x=>x.cat.Name), Status = 0, AverageResponseTime = 0, categoryId = t1.Key.CategoryID }
                            );
```

Also if someone wants to suggest a clean up to make that more readable, I would be very willing to accommodate.